# Appropriate use of education tag

Tags: discussion, tags

Our site has a tag *education*:

https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/education

and another for *education-economics*:

https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/education-economics

What is the communities view on the how these tags should be used:

- Tag use should be consistent. education is sometimes used to tag questions about those interested in learning economics (e.g. [What prerequisite courses do I need in order to specialize in Mechanism/Market design theory?](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/15652/what-prerequisite-courses-do-i-need-in-order-to-specialize-in-mechanism-market-d)) But it is also sometimes used to take questions about the economics of education ([Have there been attempts to measure the value of specific taught skills?](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/13233/have-there-been-attempts-to-measure-the-value-of-specific-taught-skills)).
- education-economics only seems to be used for the second kind of question, but is not used very often.

It seems like this needs some tidying up. Are there any suggestions about how to handle this?

Comment: Im in favor of getting rid of the education tag, It seems redundant and unclear.The self study tag or educational economics tag are more specific.

Comment: @EconJohn Good point, I had overlooked the self-study tag.

Answer (score 2):

One suggestion would be the following:

- Stadardise around the use of *education-economics* for questions about the economics of education.
- Since some people will inevitably use *education* to ask questions about the economics of education, we should create a tag-synonym that maps *education* into *education-economics*.
- Create a new tag (e.g. *learning-economics*) for questions about becoming educated in economics (although many such questions might belong on Academia.SE, which raises the question of whether we need such a tag at all).

We can create tag wikis to make the appropriate use clearer.

Answer (score 1):

One suggestion would be the following:

- Stadardise around the use of *education-economics* for questions about the economics of education.
- Since *education* is used mainly for questions about learning economics, we should adopt the convention that this tag is reserved only for such questions (and never for questions about the economics of education).

We can create tag wikis to make the appropriate use clearer.

Comment: If this is implemented education should also map to self-study.